# Exporting multiple charts as individual pdf files through loop - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to export the following charts as separate pdf files. How would i go about creating a macro/vba loop for it. Also, if I wanted them to have different names based on a column in the worksheet, how would i add that in.

[image]

I only have the code for exporting one graph which is the following. Is there a way to loop that so it does it for the other graphs.

```
Sub Macro9()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "\\stchsfs\arboari$\Profile-Data\Desktop\Export Trial1\Graph Export.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
            :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    End Sub
```

thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want a single PDF (as mentioned in the title) or multiple PDFs (as mentioned in your opening sentence)?

Comment: cybernetic.nomad - I want multiple PDFs (individual pdf files for each chart). I apologize i just reread my question and phrased it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were quite close:

```
i = 1
For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    myChart.Activate
    myPDF = "\\stchsfs\arboari$\Profile-Data\Desktop\Export Trial1\Graph Export_" & i & ".pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=myPDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    i = i + 1
Next myChart
```

Comment: It did the exporting but the charts were cut from random places. Some charts were in the same pdf.

Comment: actually it produces 6 PDF files even though i only have 5 and i found out it was because it started with the chart in the middle and with a portion of the 4th chart included in that same pdf. how do i make it so that the first chart is actually the first chart it exports? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is taking the page layout of Excel and as luck would have it, each chart matched a page in my test file, but not in yours. We'll have to see if another of way doing it is possible

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong. A blank chart was placed in the middle and it kept taking that as the first chart. Once I was able to clear the sheet of anything but the charts i wanted, the number of charts produced matched exactly what was in the sheet. Thanks again!